# Blackberry SMS interception, sending an SMS to the emulator

Tags: blackberry, sms

I am currently developing a Blackberry 5.0 application which needs to be able to intercept a SMS message. I am trying to send a SMS to the emulator. I've come accross the suggestion to run two separate instances of the emulator and to send a SMS from the one emulator instance to the other using the SMSDemo sample application on both emulators.

I run the two instances of the emulator from two separate working directories as follows:

```
"C:\java\blackberry\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.36\components\simulator\fledge.exe" /app="C:\java\blackberry\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.36\components\simulator\Jvm.dll" /sms-source-port=6000 /sms-destination-port=6001

"C:\java\blackberry\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.36\components\simulator\fledge.exe" /app="C:\java\blackberry\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.36\components\simulator\Jvm.dll" /sms-source-port=6001 /sms-destination-port=6000
```

Both instances start up but when I attempt to send a SMS it never arrives at the second emulator.

I've disabled the Windows firewall - no change.

When I netstat for UDP I can see both ports 6000 and 6001 listening.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried running this with the [BlackBerry MDS Simulator](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/5716/The_BB_MDS_Simulator_447180_11.jsp) running?  I'm not sure if there will be conflicts, but it's an easy thing to try.

Comment: Nate, I've tried it with and without the MDS simulator running, no change

Comment: I've sniffed the UDP traffic using Wireshark. I can see the datagram being sent. What is very strange is the destination address of 1.0.0.127 - looks like a swapped order version of localhost. Could this be the reason nothing arrives at the second emulator?

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on my IP stack ... I can't recall if 127.0.0.1 is the **only** address for localhost, or just the one most people use.  I'm not on a Windows box now .... can you try pinging 1.0.0.127?  Does it succeed?

Comment: 1.0.0.127 does not exist. I have no clue why the emulator uses this as the destination address. Thanks for your help with this

Comment: Hmmm ... that stinks.  Sounds like a bug. I wonder if the BlackBerry device endianness is different than that of your Windows box, and somehow a binary data value for 127.0.0.1 is getting swapped to 1.0.0.127.  I wonder if it's possible to setup a second computer on your local network with the IP address 1.0.0.127 ... and run one emulator on that machine.  This would only let you send in one direction, not both ... but maybe it helps?  Alternatively, you could try searching around for something that looks like a binary config file that may have 127.0.0.1 encoded.

Comment: Thanks Nate. I've swapped from DCHP to a static IP and added 1.0.0.127 as an alias. I'm going to take the SmsServer app apart and send UDP broadcasts to the emulator to simulate incoming SMS's.

Comment: I guess, now that I think about it, simply changing your machine's IP to 1.0.0.27 and running both emulators on that machine **might** work.  Depending on how the emulator opens up network connections (does it listen on both localhost **and** the LAN interface, or just localhost?) it might just work in both directions.  You could try that first, and then not have to worry about fiddling with routing tables on your LAN, to make 1.0.0.27 reachable.  The one and only computer you use wouldn't have to be able to communicate with any other IP addresses.  Worth a try ...

Comment: Oops.  Didn't see your answer.  I guess that did work.  Yeah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a solution for the problem. Here it is:

Using Wireshark to sniff the UDP broadcast from the emulator I noticed that the destination address is incorrect - its "1.0.0.127". This address is not routable so the datagram sent from the one emulator will never reach the other emulator.

I might have missed it but I cannot see any command line argument to set when launching the emulator to specify the destination address.

I changed my development laptop to use a  hard-coded IP address instead of DHCP. I then added 1.0.0.127 as another IP address to my TCP/IP settings. The address is now routable.

Restarted both emulators with no changes to the port settings (/sms-source-port and /sms-destination-port) and it worked fine. I did not need to use the SMSDemo application. I used the normal Blackberry messaging application.

I hope this helps others experiencing this same problem.